# Jquery queue method

Tags: jquery, queue, logic

I'm having some trouble getting my head around the jquery queue method. I've got the following code, and basically want the four parts of function textScroll to execute one after the other. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
 $.fn.pause = function (n) {
  return this.queue(function () {
    var el = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
  return $(el).dequeue();
    }, n);
  });
};

function textScroll(){

    $('#winner1, #winner2').css("display", "block")
    .pause(4000)
    .animate({left: '-1000px'}, 2000);

    $('#winner3, #winner4').fadeIn()
    .pause(4000)
    .animate({left: '-1000px'}, 2000);

    $('#winner5, #winner6').fadeIn()
    .pause(4000)
    .animate({left: '-1000px'}, 2000);

    $('.winner_scroll').css("display", "none")
    .pause(1000)
    .css("left", "1000px");
    }
```

Comment: You should look at the [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) method; it does this for you, but you'll have to use the `queue()` method to queue the `css()` call, as that doesn't use the `fx` queue by default.

Comment: Thanks Matt, could you give a brief example to show what you mean?

Comment: ` $('.winner_scroll').("display", "none")` um, missing a `.css`?

Comment: Thanks. I've been stuck on this for a while now, though that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand that last part that sets display to none, then moves it when it does not show...seems odd, but anyway:  You can hard code the variabls back in if you want, but I created them to show an example in a simplictic manner: This uses the callback of the animation to start the next one.

```
var me = {
    left: "-1000"
};
var myani = 3000;
var mywait = 4000;

function textScroll() {
    $('#winner1, #winner2').css("display", "block").animate(me, myani, function() {
        $('#winner3, #winner4').fadeIn().delay(mywait).animate(me, myani, function() {
            $('#winner5, #winner6').fadeIn().delay(mywait).animate(me, myani, function() {
                $('.winner_scroll').css("display", "none").delay(1000).css("left", "1000px");
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The CSS is bad on this: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/q3s9s/ but it is a working example.

Comment: Just to note, I don't think that last delay is really needed/doing anything as no animation should be active there (and it is not showing anyway...) up to you to decide how to handle that issue.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's really helpful. Stack Overflow is brilliant lol.